# how to use php within Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#receipt").click(function(){
var level_var = $("#receipt").val(); <?php  
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
include ('config/conn.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fixtt where acode=$acode and r_no=level_var limit 1" or die( mysql_error());
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$acode = $row['acode'];
$cramt  = $row['cr'];
$mdate  = $row['mdate'];
$rate = $row['rate'];
$rate = $row['period'];
$intpaid = $cramt * $rate / 100 ;
}
?>
});
$("input").change(function(){
var xtotal = parseFloat($("#dramt").val()) + parseFloat($("#cramt").val()) + parseFloat($("#el").val()) +
parseFloat($("#int").val()) + parseFloat($("#cl").val()) ;
document.getElementById("total").value = xtotal ;
});
}); </script>
```

Comment: Short Answer: You can't. Long answer: You can do it but its a pain in the ass :) because PHP is server side and JS is client side

Comment: You should edit your question and use the formatting tools to make the code readable. And describe what the problem is exactly.

Comment: Instead use ajax to talk to php.

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX to run the PHP scripts after loading/interacting and return the result as JSON.

This is the plan:

1. PHP-File generate the Page --> HTML with JS
2. JS interact
3. JS send AJAX request to other PHP-File
4. PHP process and create new Data
5. PHP return the Data as JSON to JS(AJAX)
6. JS consume the data and do things

Comment: i do the same u suggested like in my php which is findrecord.php